# VPN problem with internal websites

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, iis, vpn

I have installed a **VPN** server on Windows Server 2008. I can connect to and use it, but when I connect the to VPN I can't browse **internal website on my server** however I can ping them.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a DNS related issue.

Check

[Incorrect DNS server being used when using ISA VPN (Windows XP SP3 built-in client)](https://serverfault.com/questions/107352/incorrect-dns-server-being-used-when-using-isa-vpn-windows-xp-sp3-built-in-clien)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Internet Explorer as your web browser?

When you click: Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections (tab) -> LAN Settings (button) do you see "Use automatic configuration script"? If so it is probably a web proxy issue.

If not, then perhaps you have a firewall issue whereby a router, or even your web applications, have a list of allowed IPs that may view those websites; in which case you may have to ask your network administrator to allow your IP address access to that web site.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging in on PP's answer, check if the ip is listed in the exceptions for the proxy. For our site, each local address has to be in the exceptions so the proxy is bypassed for that address to make the website available.